# How to make NumberFormatter() result readable?

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I have function with number formatter.
When user enter a number in textField it's formatting and shows with additional zeros.

Example: I entered "15.45". My result "15.4500000000".

How could I make work formatter to hide 0s when the number haven't any signs after?

Example: I entered "15.45". My result is "15.45 x 0.085" = "1.31325" (Not "1.313250000000").

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 10

        if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

         year = number.doubleValue



         yearLabel.text = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: year).multiplying(by: 1))
}
```

Comment: The property `maximumFractionDigits` sets the decimal places. See http://samwize.com/2015/11/04/a-guide-to-nsnumberformatter/ . In your case it would be `formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3`.

Comment: FYI - there is no need to set the locale to `Locale.current`. That is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Try not setting `minimumSignificantDigits` to `10`, just delete that line.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10

if let number = formatter.number(from: "1.123456789") {
    formatter.string(from: number)
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid in this case i've got 3 signs after comma

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean.

Comment: If i delete this line and write "1.123456789" my result is "1.123"

Comment: It doesn't add unnecessary zeros like you asked about.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a code example of what you actually want.

Comment: @IvanKisin you just need to set the minimum and maximum fraction digits

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 10
```

to

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10
```